# SQL Server stored procedure with ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, paging

I am try to create a stored procedure that takes an index where to start, max rows to show and a location. It them returns a list of `HouseID` and the location, but I also want it to include the "name of the house" from another table called `dbo.House` which has a `HouseId` to link it to the Location. How would I go about adding the second table.

Thanks,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.basicHouseSearch 
    @StartIndex int,
    @MaxRows int,
    @HouseLocation NVarChar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Select 
       Location.HouseID, CityTown 
    FROM
       (SELECT 
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by Location.HouseID) as RowNumber,
           Location.HouseID,
           CityTown
        FROM dbo.Location) Location
    WHERE 
        RowNumber >= @StartIndex 
        AND ROWNUMBER < (@StartIndex + @MaxRows) 
END
GO
```

Comment: Add a join in your subquery and add that column in your outer query.

Comment: Or better yet, join to the results of the subquery - no guarantees but might be better at coercing SQL Server to filter before joining.

Comment: What version of Sql Server? There's a new OFFSET/FETCH technique that's much better for paging like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I re wrote your code so it uses OFFSET/FETCH (I think that it's clearer that way):

```
SELECT  L.HouseID,
        L.CityTown,
        H.Name [Name of the house]
FROM dbo.Location L
LEFT JOIN dbo.House H
    ON L.HouseID = H.HouseID
ORDER BY L.HouseID
OFFSET @StartIndex ROWS FETCH NEXT @MaxRows ONLY
```

(Requires Sql Server 2012 or later)

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Thanks, but it is giving me an error for the OFFSET and ONLY, saying incorrect syntax near 'OFFSET' and incorrect syntax near 'ONLY' expecting FROM

Comment: @user3043862 So, is the server where that database belongs actually SQL Server 2012?, and what is the compatibility level of your database?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Ya, it was not set to 2012 compatibility. Thank You

Comment: @user3043862 What compat level was it in? I have no problems running that syntax on a 2012 database in 90 compat (and it can't be any earlier than that).

Comment: @user3043862 Where are you getting this error message? After some testing, I suspect this is coming from Visual Studio or SQL Server Data Tools, not SQL Server. The "expecting FROM" bit makes me highly skeptical this was a compatibility level issue in the SQL Server engine. Or, maybe, you were running it on a 2008 database.

Answer (score 3):

I re wrote your code so it uses a CTE (I think that it's clearer that way):

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER by L.HouseID),
            L.HouseID,
            L.CityTown,
            H.Name [Name of the house]
    FROM dbo.Location L
    LEFT JOIN dbo.House H
        ON L.HouseID = H.HouseID
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RowNumber >= @StartIndex 
AND RowNumber < (@StartIndex + @MaxRows)
```

Comment: Hey, I sorta piled on from your answer for the humor factor. Please don't take it the wrong way: prior to Sql Server 2012 I think this is the right answer.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Not at all :-). For op's version your answer is better I think

Comment: Also: edited this one instead of my own by mistake (rolled back now). That's what I get for copy/paste :/

Comment: @Joel and note that OFFSET/FETCH is just syntactic sugar, in all cases I've tested the performance is identical. Been meaning to blog about that... Well, I kind of did, but [that was ages ago (2012 was still in beta)](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/11/10/sql-server-11-denali-using-the-offset-clause.aspx). Some good links in the comments, too.